# Why setxkbmap in .bashrc is intermittently working? Why it takes awhile to load after PC has already started?

Tags: bash, bashrc, shortcut-keys

I am using this on my `.bashrc` file:

```
## SWAP CONTROL KEY

setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

I did this, basically, because I am using Emacs a lot. It seems to work most of the time.

Unfortunately, 2 problems keep happening:

(i) - After the PC starts, it takes a while to work. It is not instantaneous which intrigues me, since this seems to be something "small" to change;

(ii) - Sometimes, out of the blue, it has stopped working, and then, suddenly, the swap is back. This happened one time today.

Although it was just one time, it is really annoying because I have changed the keybinding recently. So, I am already making mistakes sometimes while getting used to it. If I cannot trust this keybinding, the mistakes are going to be even more frequent.

I have a huge knowledge gap on `.bashrc` file configurations. Maybe, there is some inconsistency in my file. Here is a repository on GitHub showing the [whole .bashrc file](https://github.com/pdelfino/my-bashrc/blob/main/.bashrc).

Thanks.

Comment: `.bashrc` is only referenced with the terminal opening into a login shell.  Unless you're logging directly into a terminal login shell (Bash) it won't load at start.  It also may not be persistent.  GUI environments though don't refer to `.bashrc` when you load up on boot.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasWard. This explanation makes a lot of sense. Do you recommend another place for me to insert this `setxkbmap`  definition?  I would like to have it as a persistent change and loading up on boot.

Comment: I have a couple of potential solutions but i am on the tail end of a very long day and heading to sleep, will share my thoughts tomorrow after sleep.

Comment: No problem. Have a nice rest :)

Comment: TYPICALLY this is done in `/etc/rc.local` but that's more or less deprecated nowadays in favor of SystemD oneshot units at boot time.  Which would work for literally the entire system (or they should anyways).  Let me write up an example in an answer.  If it works, great, if not, we'll keep chugging along on potential solutions.

Comment: I'm assuming my cronjob answer solved the issue for you?  Was about to write up the SystemD approach but won't if the cronjob solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, one of the problems you're encountering is the evil that is "`.bashrc` is only read for Bash shells in the terminal".  Your GUI is NOT a Bash shell, so `.bashrc` is NOT read by the GUI until you open the Terminal and then it activates/applies the keychange.

If we want it to work globally it needs to execute as part of the system independent of the `.bashrc`.  There're two options: Your user crontab for `@reboot` which is a special case name.  OR, a SystemD unit.

(I've tested neither solution, so I can't comment if one will work better than the other, if at all).

Let's start with the cron job option first.

**Cron job approach**

Open your terminal, and run `crontab -e`.

Add this line to it:

```
@reboot setxkbmap -option ctrl:swapcaps
```

Reboot your system, and see if this works.

If it works, great.  If not, then we have to try another approach.

**Fallback Solution: Autorun gnome-terminal after login**

If all else fails, add `gnome-terminal` to your startup applications.

First, install `gnome-startup-applications`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-startup-applications
```

Secondly, search your applications for "Startup Applications Preferences"

Add an item for `gnome-terminal`.  That way it'll autorun the terminal automatically.

Comment: Thanks. It *almost* works. After start-up, it does not work. But if I open the shell it works. This was already possible. But now I can close the shell (terminal) and it keeps working!

Comment: I will try to insert `gnome-terminal` on my start-up preferences. So, I think it will work.

Comment: OK then this looks like a case of just adding gnome-terminal to your startup apps.